# How to remove vertical space between two tikz matrix rows?

Tags: tikz-pgf, spacing

I have the following matrix in TikZ:

[image: example showing unnecessary vertical space]

Here's the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    circled/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt},
    highrow/.style={minimum height=.9cm},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix of nodes] (tcm) {
    {}  &
    $a_{00}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{10}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{20}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n0}$  \\
    {}  &
    $a_{01}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{11}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{21}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n1}$ \\
    {}  &
    $a_{02}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{12}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{22}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n2}$  \vspace{-5cm}\\
    |[circled]| $+$  &
    |[highrow]| $\vdots$  &  {}  &
    $\vdots$  &  {}  &
    $\vdots$  &  {}  &
    $\ddots$  &  {}  &
    $\vdots$  \\
    {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{0m}$  &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{1m}$  &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{2m}$  &  {}  &
    $\cdots$                           &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{nm}$  \\
  };
  \node[fit=(tcm-5-1) (tcm-5-2) (tcm-5-3) (tcm-5-4) (tcm-5-5) (tcm-5-6) (tcm-5-7) (tcm-5-8) (tcm-5-9) (tcm-5-10),inner sep=0pt] (R5) {};
  \draw (R5.north -| tcm.west) -- (R5.north -| tcm.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The amount of vertical space between the third and fourth rows is bothering me. The fourth row (the row that follows the circled plus sign) has a lot of vertical space above, and I can't remove it. As far as I know, `row sep` only works for all the rows at once -- I can't use it in only the fourth row.

OBS: The source of the problem is not the `minimum height` of the circled plus sign. When this minimum height is set to zero, the fourth row has an abnormal amount of vertical space above it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "standard" `tabular` adjustments work so that you can use `\\[-4mm]`, for example, to decrease the space between two consecutive rows. Similarly, `\\[3em]` will add `3em` of space. If you do this then your diagram becomes:

[image]

Here is the full code (which is the OP's with this single adjustment):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    circled/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt},
    highrow/.style={minimum height=.9cm},
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix of nodes] (tcm) {
    {}  &
    $a_{00}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{10}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{20}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n0}$  \\
    {}  &
    $a_{01}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{11}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{21}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n1}$ \\
    {}  &
    $a_{02}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{12}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{22}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n2}$  \\[-4mm]
    |[circled]| $+$  &
    |[highrow]| $\vdots$  &  {}  &
    $\vdots$  &  {}  &
    $\vdots$  &  {}  &
    $\ddots$  &  {}  &
    $\vdots$  \\
    {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{0m}$  &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{1m}$  &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{2m}$  &  {}  &
    $\cdots$                           &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{nm}$  \\
  };
  \node[fit=(tcm-5-1) (tcm-5-2) (tcm-5-3) (tcm-5-4) (tcm-5-5) (tcm-5-6) (tcm-5-7) (tcm-5-8) (tcm-5-9) (tcm-5-10),inner sep=0pt] (R5) {};
  \draw (R5.north -| tcm.west) -- (R5.north -| tcm.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't know about the "standard" tabular ajustments, hehe. Thanks!

Comment: Nice. By adding `[matrix of nodes,nodes in empty cells]` you can omit the empty braces `{}`

Answer (score 2):

The additional vertical space comes from the height of `\vdots` and `\ddots` as you can see with

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[inner sep=0pt,draw]{$\vdots$};
\end{document}
```

[image]

So I would use `$\smash{\vdots}$` to hide the height of the dots and a style like `strutsize/.style={text height=\ht\strutbox,text depth=\dp\strutbox}` to reserve the needed vertical space.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amssymb}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,calc,fit}
\begin{document}

\tikzset{
    circled/.style={draw,circle,inner sep=0pt},
    highrow/.style={minimum height=.9cm},
    strutsize/.style={text height=\ht\strutbox,text depth=\dp\strutbox}
}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node[matrix of nodes] (tcm) {
    {}  &
    $a_{00}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{10}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{20}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n0}$  \\
    {}  &
    $a_{01}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{11}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{21}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n1}$ \\
    {}  &
    $a_{02}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{12}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $a_{22}$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\cdots$  &  $\leqslant$  &
    $\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{n2}$ \\
    |[circled]| $+$  &
    |[strutsize]| $\smash{\vdots}$  &  {}  &
    $\smash{\vdots}$  &  {}  &
    $\smash{\vdots}$  &  {}  &
    $\smash{\ddots}$  &  {}  &
    $\smash{\vdots}$  \\
    {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{0m}$  &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{1m}$  &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty a_{2m}$  &  {}  &
    $\cdots$                           &  {}  &
    $\sum\limits_{m=0}^\infty \lim\limits_{n\to\infty} a_{nm}$  \\
  };
  \node[fit=(tcm-5-1) (tcm-5-2) (tcm-5-3) (tcm-5-4) (tcm-5-5) (tcm-5-6) (tcm-5-7) (tcm-5-8) (tcm-5-9) (tcm-5-10),inner sep=0pt] (R5) {};
  \draw (R5.north -| tcm.west) -- (R5.north -| tcm.east);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, good to know that `vdots` has this strange behaviour. Thanks!